# How can I transform old navigation to responsive bootstrap nav without changing its look?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change navigation of old site so that it will become responsive. I can't change the look of the navigation on big screen. I am not able to getthe desired look with bootstrap navigation. I would like to know if it is possible to do it using bootstrap. The navigation also need to be fixed at top when scrolling. Is there any repo or can any one help this issue?

**I tried but not able to get using following codes**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="img/summan-company.png" alt="Summan" /></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
       <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left ">
       <div class="row">
       </div>
       <div class="row">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
              <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
              <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

       </div>
           </div>
          </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Desired look
[image: old navigation to be changed using bootstrap but retaining its look]
What I got from above codes

[image: what I got from above code]
what I want is the right part on above should be little downward as in first image and there should be a row for placing language bar from google.

Comment: how about making a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Raptor  Yes you can create in jsfiidle.  the old site is on old HTML 4 version so I think we should just use the look visually and create it using HTML 5 and bootstrap.